# After updating Xcode to version 14, the error: 'Table' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swiftui

Updated Xcode to the latest version (14.0 (14A309)) and there was an error with the SQLite package (v. 0.13.3). Has anyone already encountered a similar situation, any ideas how to solve it? Thanks in advance and have a nice day.
[image]

Comment: Try `SQLite.Table`instead of just `Table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI got a new View called [`Table`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table)

so now the compiler doesn't know of you mean `SwiftUI.Table` or `SQLite.Table`

You can specify which `Table` by prefixing it like this `SQLite.Table` or if you don't need anything from `SwiftUI` in this file then you could simply remove the import.